# XML parsing using attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have XML-based config for application shortcuts bindings. i need to parse it.

```
<ShortcutBinding>
  <ShortcutHandler Name ="Retail.Application.Documents.Outcome.Presentation.OutcomePresenter">
    <Shortcut Name="EditHeader">
      <Key>CTRL</Key>
      <Key>F4</Key>
    </Shortcut>
    <Shortcut Name="EditItem">
      <Key>F4</Key>
    </Shortcut>
  </ShortcutHandler>  
</ShortcutBinding>
```

I know that .Net has attributes for deserializing XML into objects.
Can anyone write complete example for such deserialization, using attributes.

Comment: may be it's will helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ShortcutBinding
{
    public ShortcutHandler ShortcutHandler { get; set; }
}

public class ShortcutHandler
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Shortcut")]
    public List<Shortcut> Shortcuts { get; set; }
}

public class Shortcut
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Key")]
    public List<string> Keys { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ShortcutBinding));
var binding = (ShortcutBinding)serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(path));
```

Comment: one more question, how can i convert Key from string representation to appropriate enumeration representation? so i want to take

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi just change keys type from `List<string>` to `List<yourEnumType>` and make sure you are storing enum names in xml. E.g. `CTRL` is not a valid enum name for `ConsoleKey` enum.

Comment: so what about custom converters?

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi define property on `Shortcut` class which will do custom logic on strings which you deserialized from xml. E.g.         `public List<ConsoleKey> ConsoleKeys { get { return Keys.Select(k => (ConsoleKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleKey), k)).ToList(); } }`